# Knockout onClick with dynamic data as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an addToCart function I'd like to utilize that is NOT in my viewModel.

In my view model I have an object `{"items":[ {"name":"siren","id":2,"image":"s3.amazon.com"}])`

And in my knockout app:

```
<div id="cart" class="shopify-buy__cart-scroll">
            <div class="shopify-buy__cart-items" data-bind="foreach: newcart.items">
                <div class="shopify-buy__cart-item">
                    <div data-bind="style: { 'background-image': 'url(' + images + ')'}" class="shopify-buy__cart-item__image" alt="Product" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size: contain;"></div>
                    <span class="shopify-buy__cart-item__title" data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    <span class="shopify-buy__cart-item__price" data-bind="text: price "></span>
                    <div class="shopify-buy__quantity-container">
                        <button class="shopify-buy__btn--seamless shopify-buy__quantity-decrement" type="button">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M4 7h8v2H4z"></path></svg>
                        </button>
                        <input class="shopify-buy__quantity shopify-buy__cart-item__quantity-input" type="number" min="0" aria-label="Quantity" data-bind="attr: {value: quantity}" style="height: 30px; border:solid 1px #d3dbe2 !important;padding-left:13px;" />
                        <button class="shopify-buy__btn--seamless shopify-buy__quantity-increment" type="button" databind="click: addToCard(id)" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M12 7H9V4H7v3H4v2h3v3h2V9h3z"></path></svg>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="shopify-buy__cart-bottom">
                <p class="shopify-buy__cart__subtotal__text" >SUBTOTAL</p>
                <p class="shopify-buy__cart__subtotal__price"data-bind="text: total"></p>
                <p class="shopify-buy__cart__notice">Shipping and discount codes are added at checkout.</p>
                <button class="shopify-buy__btn shopify-buy__btn--cart-checkout" type="button">CHECKOUT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In this line: `<button class="shopify-buy__btn--seamless shopify-buy__quantity-decrement" type="button">`

I want to add some a function with a dynamic parameter.

```
<button class="shopify-buy__btn--seamless shopify-buy__quantity-incriment" type="button" databind="attr: {onclick:addToCart( id ) }">
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do this without adding the function to my viewmodel. It's only an object and I'd like to keep it that way.

Thanks!

Comment: where is `addToCart` function in a global `window` object ? if it's a global then you can use `databind="click: window.addToCart()"`. However, i am not sure where you are getting the value `id` from..

Comment: The ID value is passed in through an array of objects that's initialized through ko.applyBindings(obj). It needs to be found in foreach

Answer (score 0):

how about using the html5 data attribute.  to get your knockout id into your click function.

```
data-bind="attr: {'data-idfromko': id }"
```

run snippet below.

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.theArray = ko.observableArray([{
    'id': 1,
    'foo': 'bar'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'foo': 'bar2'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'foo': 'bar3'
  }, ]);

}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
  $('.button').click(function(event) {
    value = $(this).data("idfromko" )
    alert(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <</thead>
      <tbody data-bind=foreach:theArray>
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text:id"></td>
          <td data-bind="text:foo"></td>
          <td>
            <button class="button"  
            data-bind="attr: {'data-idfromko': id }">
              click
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```